# Inconsistent accessibility field type calling a static field in a static class

Tags: c#, static

I can't call a static field (inside a static class) from another class.
I always get an accessibility field error.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Business
{
    public static class ListesXML
    {
        public static List<ActionXML> listActionXML = new List<ActionXML>();
        public static List<VarActionXML> listVarActionXML = new List<VarActionXML>();

        public static void getXMLFile()
        {
            listActionXML.Clear();
            listVarActionXML.Clear();
            .....
        }
    }
 }
```

I try to access `listActionXML` from the same namespace public static class like this:

```
 ListesXML.listActionXML
```

Error:

```
Erreur  1   Accessibilité incohérente : le type de champ 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Business.ActionXML>' est moins accessible que le champ 'Business.ListesXML.listActionXML' H:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AutomateZen\Business\ListesXML.cs   14  39  Business
```

Why does is this error shown and how do I fix this?

Comment: Please the spelling error.

Comment: You are trying to assign a public List to a private List. You do not show us the assignment here, though.

Comment: Are the classes `ActionXML` and `VarActionXML` public?

Comment: Can you please post the *actual* compiler error? Because the error message you've posted is not making sense. Please highlight the error message in the error list in Visual Studio and copy it with Ctrl+C instead of retyping a garbled version of it.

Comment: Show us the declarations of `ActionXML` and `VarActionXML`. Most likely, they are private, protected or internal.

Comment: Thank you Scoregraphix, that was the problem. They were not public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you've posted does not make sense:

- `System.Collections.Generic.List` is not a field, nor is it not public

Most likely the error message is referring to the types `ActionXML` or `VarActionXML`, complaining that they're less accessible than the public fields you've tried to create.

So check the declarations of `ActionXML` and `VarActionXML`, most likely they're one of the following:

```
class ActionXML
internal class ActionXML
```

but should be:

```
public class ActionXML
public class VarActionXML
```

Comment: I updated my post, thank you, the problem was that both ActionXML and VarActionXML were not public

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the `ActionXML` class from a more privileged class. Please define the access modifier in the definition of class `ActionXML` as `public` like below:

```
public class ActionXML
{
    // ...
}
```